# Get minimum Euclidean distance between a given vector and vectors in the database

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql, math

I store 128D vectors in PostgreSQL table as double precision []:

```
create table tab (
   id integer,
   name character varying (200),
   vector double precision []
 )
```

For a given vector, I need to return one record from the database with the minimum Euclidean distance between this vector and the vector in the table entry.

I have a function that computes the Euclidean distance of two vectors according to the known formula SQRT ((v11-v21) ^ 2 + (v1 [2] -v2 [2]) ^ 2 + .... + (v1 [128] -v2 [128] ]) ^ 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.euclidian (
  arr1 double precision [],
  arr2 double precision [])
  RETURNS double precision AS
$ BODY $
  select sqrt (SUM (tab.v)) as euclidian from (SELECT
     UNNEST (vec_sub (arr1, arr2)) as v) as tab;
$ BODY $
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
```

Ancillary function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.vec_sub (
  arr1 double precision [],
  arr2 double precision [])
RETURNS double precision [] AS
$ BODY $
  SELECT array_agg (result)
    FROM (SELECT (tuple.val1 - tuple.val2) * (tuple.val1 - tuple.val2)
        AS result
        FROM (SELECT UNNEST ($ 1) AS val1
               , UNNEST ($ 2) AS val2
               , generate_subscripts ($ 1, 1) AS ix) tuple
    ORDER BY ix) inn;
$ BODY $
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
```

Query:

```
select tab.id as tabid, tab.name as tabname,
        euclidian ('{0.1,0.2,...,0.128}', tab.vector) as eucl from tab
order by eulc ASC
limit 1
```

Everything works fine since I have several thousands of records in tab. But the DB is going to be grown and I need to avoid full scan of tab running the query, add a kind of index search. Would be great to filter-out at least 80% of records by index, the remaining 20% can be handled by full scan.

One of the current directions of the solution search: PostGIS extension allows to search and sort by distance (ST_3DDistance), filter by distance (ST_3DWithin), etc. This works great and fast using indicies. Is it possible to abstract for N-dimensional space?

Some observations:

- all coordinate values are between [-0.5...0.5] (I do not know exactly, I think [-1.0 ...1.0] are theoretical limits)
- the vectors are not normalized, the distance from (0,0,... 0) is in range [1.2...1.6].

[That is the translated post from StackExchange Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764135/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8).

Comment: approximately how many vectors will the DB store and how long can you wait for one search?

Comment: @Petar Petrovic we expect to get several handreds of thousands (up to million) and we need to get results in ~300 ms (without network routing)

Comment: As an unhelpful note, you don't need to compute the actual distance-- you can compute the distance squared, which is easier, and sorts the same as distance (larger distance is equivalent to larger distance squared).

Comment: @barrycarter thanks for the valuable note, even more - I can sort by (|v1[1]-v2[1]|+|v1[2]-v2[2]|+ ...+|v1[128]-v2[128]|) - then calculate Euclidian for only one returned record

Comment: @EugeneBartosh, unfortunately your last idea doesn't work unless your real target metric is actually a [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). Otherwise [L1 and L2 distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) are not the same. Example: for `(0.9; 0)` obviously `L1 = L2 = 0.9`, for `(0.5; 0.5)` distances are `L1 = 0.5 + 0.5 = 1` and `L2 = sqrt(0.5^2 + 0.5^2) = sqrt(2)/2  ≈ 0.7`. So `L1(0.9; 0) < L1(0.5; 0.5)` while `L2(0.9; 0) > L2(0.5; 0.5)`

Comment: @EugeneBartosh Have you considered using `cube` extension ?

Answer (score 2):

Like @SaiBot hints at with local sensitivity hashing (LSH), there are plenty of researched techniques that allow you to run approximate nearest neighbors (ANN) searches. You have to accept a speed/accuracy tradeoff, but this is reasonable for most production scenarios since a brute-force approach to find the exact neighbors tends to be computationally prohibitive.

This [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/comprehensive-guide-to-approximate-nearest-neighbors-algorithms-8b94f057d6b6) is an excellent overview of current state-of-the-art algorithms along with their pros and cons. Below, I've linked several popular open-source implementations. All 3 have Python bindings

- Facebook [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss)
- Spotify [Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy)
- Google [ScaNN](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/scann)

Answer (score 1):

With a 128 dimensional data constrained to PostgreSQL you will have no choice than to apply a full scan for each query.

Even highly optimized index structures for indexing high-dimensional data like the [X-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-tree) or the [IQ-Tree](http://www.dbs.informatik.uni-muenchen.de/Publikationen/Papers/iqtree.final.pdf) will have problems with that many dimensions and usually offer no big benefit over the pure scan.

The main issue here is the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) that will let index structures degenerate above 20ish dimensions.

Newer work thus considers the problem of approximate nearest neighbor search, since in a lot of applications with this many dimensions it is sufficient to find a good answer, rather than the best one. [Locality Sensitive Hashing](http://people.csail.mit.edu/indyk/p117-andoni.pdf) is among these approaches.

**Note:** Even if an index structure is able to filter out 80% of the records, you will have to access the remaining 20% of the records by random access operations from disk (making the application I/O bound), which will be even slower than reading all the data in one scan and computing the distances.

Answer (score 0):

You could looking at [Computational Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry) which is a field dedicated to efficient algorithms. There is generally a tradeoff between the amount of data stored and efficiency of an algorithm. So by adding data we can reduce speed. In particular, we are looking at a [Nearest neighbour search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) the algorithm below uses a form of space partitioning.

Lets consider the 3D case as the distances from the origin lie in a narrow range it looks like they are clustered around a fuzzy sphere. Divide space into sub 8 cubes depending on the sign of each coordinate, label these +++, ++- etc. We can work out the minimum distance from the test vector to a vector in each cube.

Say our test vector is (0.4,0.5,0.6). The minimum distance from that to the +++ cube is zero. The minimum distance to the -++ cube is 0.4 as the closest vector in the -++ cube would be (-0.0001,0.5,0.6). Likewise, the minimum distances to +-+ is 0.5, ++-: 0.6, --+: sqrt(.4^2+.5^2) etc.

The algorithms then becomes: First search the cube the test vector is in and find the minimum distance to all the vectors in that cube. If that distance is smaller than the minimum distance to the other cubes then we are done. If not search the next closest cube until no vector in any other cube could be closer.

If we were to implement this is a database we would compute a key for each vector. In 3D this is a 3-bit integer with 0 or 1 in each bit depending on the sign of the coordinate + (0), - (-). So first select WHERE key = 000, then where key = 100, etc.

You can think of this as a type of hash function which has been specifically designed to make finding close points easy. I think these are called [Locality-sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)

The high dimensions of your data make things much trickier. With 128 dimensions just using the signs of coordinates give 2^128 = 3.4E+38 possibilities. This is far too many hash buckets and some form of dimension reduction is needed.

You might be able to choose k points and partition space according to which of those you are closest too.